# How to display errors from model-less form (form_tag or form_with) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Omniauth with devise, when provider doesn't sent email user needs to confirm it manually (in order to create new user in db). I render this without passing any arguments:

```
render 'omniauth_callbacks/confirm_email'
```

confirm_email.html.slim looks like this - it has no model:

```
h1 Enter your email
= form_with(url: confirm_email_path, method: :post) do |f|
    = f.label :Email
    = f.email_field :email
  = f.submit 'Confirm email'
```

Submit button leads to a method which creates pending user and authorization and sends confirmation mail to provided email.

```
 def confirm_email
    pending_user = User.find_or_init_skip_confirmation(params[:email])
    if pending_user 
      authorization = pending_user.authorizations.create!(provider: session[:auth]['provider'], uid: session[:auth]['uid'], 
                                                linked_email: params[:email], confirmation_token: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20],
                                                confirmation_sent_at: Time.now)

      OauthMailer.send_confirmation_letter(authorization).deliver_now
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Great! Now confirm your email, we've sent you a letter!"
    else
      render 'omniauth_callbacks/confirm_email', alert: "We couldn't verify your email, please try again later"
    end 
  end
```

Everything works fine but I don't know how to display errors which may occur. All errors are pretty visible in console, e.g. I've got:

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Uid has already been taken) - when confirmation email was already sent to email.
or

ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (You cannot call create unless the parent is saved) - when email was blank and I couldn't create pending user.

Normally I would use standard `render 'shared/errors', resource: resource`, but it requires resource which I don't have in my form_with.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in a begin/rescue structure:

```rb
def confirm_email
  begin 
    pending_user = User.find_or_init_skip_confirmation(params[:email])
    if pending_user
      authorization = pending_user.authorizations.
                                   create!(provider: session[:auth]['provider'],
                                           uid: session[:auth]['uid'], 
                                           linked_email: params[:email],
                                           confirmation_token: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20],
                                           confirmation_sent_at: Time.now)

      OauthMailer.send_confirmation_letter(authorization).deliver_now
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Great! Now confirm your email, we've sent you a letter!"
    else
      raise "We couldn't verify your email, please try again later"
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    render 'omniauth_callbacks/confirm_email', alert: "ERROR: #{e.message}"
  end 
end
```